# Passing serializable through intent causing ClassCastException error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am passing a HashMap with key-value pairs Long[] and String from one activity to another and then putting the HashMap data into a TreeMap so it'll be sorted. To pass the data I made a for loop of the HashMap data.

Here is the code for the activity that is sending the Intent:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    HashMap<Long[], String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        hashmap.put(new Long[]{(long) i * 20, (long) i * 30}, "home" + i);
    }
    intent.putExtra("this", hashmap);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the code in the AnotherActivity class that is receiving the intent:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

    // Sorts the long values in TreeMap
    Comparator<Long[]> sortByTime = new Comparator<Long[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Long[] one, Long[] two) {
            if (one[0] > two[0]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (one[0] < two[0]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<Long[], String> data = new HashMap<Long[], String>();
    data = (HashMap<Long[], String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("this");
    TreeMap<Long[], String> dic = new TreeMap<Long[], String>(sortByTime);
    for (Map.Entry<Long[], String> dat : data.entrySet()) {
        dic.put(dat.getKey(), dat.getValue());
    }
}
```

The ClassCastException error which happens at the dic.put(dat.getKey(), dat.getValue()); (line 44) and the custome Comparator start (line 26):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Long[]
        at com.mercurio.test.AnotherActivity$1.compare(AnotherActivity.java:26)
        at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java:277)
        at java.util.TreeMap.putInternal(TreeMap.java:240)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:186)
        at com.mercurio.test.AnotherActivity.onCreate(AnotherActivity.java:44)
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. I can't seem to find any way to find a way to fix this error.

**Edit**: Accidently wrote ArrayList instead of TreeMap for dic. 
Added custom comparator. Changed the for loop to iterate over the entryset.

Comment: what's the line 24 ?

Comment: ArrayList<Long[]> dic = new ArrayList<>(data.keySet());

Comment: its the for(Long[] dat : data.keySet())

Comment: yes, Instead of ArrayList<Long[]> dic = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Long[] dat : data.keySet()) {
        dic.add(dat);
    }

Comment: I do apologize Mobeen, I accidently wrote dic as an ArrayList when it is actually a TreeMap I am trying to add the data to. Your solution does actually work for an ArrayList, is there a way I can use this solution if dic is actually a TreeMap?

Comment: Treemap is sorted order map based on key. Long[] is not implement the Comparable<> so it is give exception.treemap key Object should be with comparable

Comment: after treemap now your exception happen on this line.  dic.put(dat, String.valueOf(i));

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Is there a way to continue using Long[] or do I have to use a class the implements Comparable like Long? I just tried making a custom comparator for the treemap but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a String attribute to AnotherActivity: `public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="msg";`. Assuming the classes are in the same package, put the extra into the intent like this: `intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE", hashmap);` and retrieve the intent from AntotherActivity like this: `intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);`

This would be AnotherActivity:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="msg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<Long[], String> data = new HashMap<Long[], String>();
    data = (HashMap<Long[], String>) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    ArrayList<Long[]> dic = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Long[] dat : data.keySet()) {
        dic.add(dat);
    }
}
```

And this would be MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    HashMap<Long[], String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        hashmap.put(new Long[]{(long) i * 20, (long) i * 30}, "home" + i);
    }
    intent.putExtra(AnotherActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, hashmap);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: OK, so I tried using EXTRA_MESSAGE and ts still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this loop ( looping on `entrySet` ) instead of looping on `keySet` :

```
HashMap<Long[], String> data = new HashMap<Long[], String>();

for(Entry<Long[], String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    Long[] key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    // do what you have to do here
}
```

**EDIT :** A tree map maintains its keys in sorted order. Arrays does not define any ordering, so it cannot be used as a key directly. You can supply an external `Comparator` impose an order though, but you must define an ordering that makes sense to you:

```
TreeMap<Long[], String> dic = new TreeMap<>(
    new Comparator<Long[]>() {
        public int compare(Long[] l1, Long[] l2) {
            // define your order
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried looping through the entry set and adding it to the TreeMap: dic.put(dat.getKey(), dat.getValue()); with data : data.entrySet() and now I get a ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; is not Comparable error at the dic.put(dat.getKey(), dat.getValue());

Comment: I added a custom comparator and I get the ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Long[] error  but at the dic.put(dat, data.get(dat));

Comment: @PinkyMystique combine both solutions to get it works it's an edit so add the edit to the first solution, so keep using enrySet and use custom comparator

Comment: I've changed the for loop to interate over the entryset and I still get the ClassCastException error, except now it is when I put the data into the TreeMap.